# CSS Speech Bubble hover change color

Tags: html, css

I'm using a css speech bubble generator to generate a speech bubble, but when I hover over the speech bubble, the speech bubble needs to change to be white. The little arrow bit that sticks out however is not changing to be white.

Code:

styling in the php code:

```
<style>
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 65px;
padding: 0px;
background: #ff8282;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 0 15px 24px;
border-color: transparent #ff8282;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
margin-top: -15px;
right: -24px;
top: 50%;
}

#go-button:hover .bubble:after {
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background: #ffffff;
}

.bubble:hover {
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background: #ffffff;
}
.bubble:hover .bubble:after {
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background: #ffffff;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
            <div  type="submit"
                value="GO"
                id="go-button"
                class="bubble">
            </div>
```

In a seperate stylesheet:

```
#go-button,
#add-go-button,
#show-shops-button,
#show-comments-button,
#edit-product-button {
  font: 200 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff8282;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#go-button h5,
#add-go-button h5 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
#go-button:hover,
#add-go-button:hover,
#try-now-button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #fc4747;
}
```

image of problem:

[image]

How come the arrow bit of the speech bubble is not changing to white when hovering over the #go-button div (the rectangular portion of the speech bubble is turning white when hovering - just not the arrow portion)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
#go-button:hover .bubble:after {
      border-color: transparent #ffffff;
}
```

to

```
#go-button.bubble:hover:after {
      border-color: transparent  #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sL9qz39a/)

**just change:**

```
#go-button:hover .bubble::after {
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background: #ffffff;
}
```

**to:**

```
#go-button:hover:after {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 0 15px 24px;
border-color: transparent #ffffff;
}
```

*No need to use class from same element that you used ID for hovering after.*

Answer (score 0):

Following the below instructions should fix the issue.

**Remove**

```
#go-button:hover .bubble:after {
      border-color: #ffffff;
      background: #ffffff;
}
```

**Replace**

```
.bubble:hover .bubble:after {
      border-color: #fff;
      background: transparent;
}
```

**With**

```
.bubble:hover::after {
      border-color: #fff;
      background: transparent;
}
```

Hope it helps